# Gaussian Mixture Model-UBM based for image recognition

Tags: image-processing, matlab, gaussian, speech-recognition

Scenario:

1. Open set recognition: Unknown individuals may appear on scene (CCTV).
2. Gallery = 10 individuals with a mug-shot image per individual.

Approach:
**Gaussian Mixture Model-UBM based**

1. Use video sequences of 20 individuals of random people that might not appear in the gallery or in the scene as UBM (universal background model).

   ubm = gmm_em(datalist, numberOfMixtures, EMiterations, downSamplingfactor, parallelWorker)

*'datalist'* contain **feature vector of each individuals** that assigned as UBM `(20xnumberOfvideoSequences) cells`. Each cell contains `[numberOfMixtures x numberOfFrames] double`.

2. Adapt the ubm into each individuals (in gallery) to create GMM speaker model.

   ```
   for I = 1:numberOfIndividuals gmm{s} = mapAdapt(spkFiles(I,:),ubm, map_tau, config) end
   ```

*spkFiles* contain **feature vector of the mugshot images** for each individuals in the gallery. `(10 x 1) cells`, which each cell contain *[numberOfMixtures x 1] double*.

The approach above is based on [MSR toolkit for speaker verification.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52279) However, I'm not so sure about implementing it for image verification. Is it what I had described above is correct?
The way to prepare the *datalist* and *spkFiles*?
How to decide the number of mixtures? Can I use any feature extraction method such as PCA?